# How To Manually Sync Database From Development To Production Server

Tags: mysql, synchronization, mariadb

## Server/IP Address:

- Development Server: www-dev (172.22.12.42, Debian 10)
- Administration Server for www-dev: www-admin (172.22.69.25, Debian 10)
- Production Server: graysonpeddie.com (172.22.203.247, CentOS 8)

All of my IP addresses are part of the ZeroTier network.

## Scenario and Research

Let's say I have just published my blog article using my administration panel (www-admin). www-admin connects to the database in www-dev and inserts a new row into the table once all the checks are completed in www-dev. I test to make sure I see a new blog article posted in www-dev. Then, I do a mysqldump from www-dev, scp the .sql file to graysonpeddie.com, ssh to graysonpeddie.com, and imported the file into my MySQL database.

Here's what an administration panel look like for www-admin:

[image: An administration panel showing a list of blog articles]

[image: An administration panel showing a list of categories]

So the administration panel in www-admin talks to the development database server in www-dev.

Everything is fine and dandy, but with mysqldump, scp, ssh, and mysql command, I want to do all this in one command. Maybe something like:

`mysqldump -u graysonpeddie_admin -p graysonpeddie_blog | ssh username@graysonpeddie.com "mysql -u graysonpeddie_admin -p graysonpeddie_blog"`

But that is a lot to type and this is only a pseudo example. And plus, I would have to input passwords a couple of times for both development and production database server.

Or since I have configured my production firewall to open 3306 for 172.22.203.247 (that's a private ZeroTier IP address, by the way), I could do something like this:

`mysqldump -u graysonpeddie_admin -p graysonpeddie_blog | mysql -u graysonpeddie_blog -p -h 172.22.203.247 graysonpeddie_blog`

But the problem with that is I get `Enter password: Enter password:` and that's not going to work.

I've seen tutorials about how to setup master/slave replication, where the development server will be the master and production server will be the slave, but all the changes I make in my development server will be automatic and not manual. I want to perform the replication step **manually**. That is:

1. Make changes to the database in the development server.
2. Test the changes by visiting https[://]www-dev (I put [ and ] to not make www-dev a link).
3. If all goes well, push the changes to the database in the production server (graysonpeddie.com).

I mean, is there another one-word for "manual?" An opposite of "automatic?" Because I've done a Google search for mysql manual replication and I even had "manual replication" in quotes. That did not help as that would lead me to mysql.com for a manual of how to setup replication. the word "manual" has more than one definition.

Anyway, I don't mind software suggestions as long as it's open source and in GNU/GPL. I've had a look at [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/), but I'm not sure if this can be hosted in my administration server (www-admin). However, if I'm doing any kind of source control, I want to do this in a command line, so that I can write functionality in my administration panel that syncs changes from my development server to a production server, but only if all goes well during testing phase.

Comment: I think you are approaching setting up the database environment from a wrong angle! You should write the code that moves the database structure and perhaps some lookup / configuration data from one release to another and store it as part of your code version control system and apply it as part of pushing the new code to the production servers. Mysqldump is too crude for this task, since it can only export the existing structure only, not how you get from one version to another.

Comment: Actually, I think I found a page that allows me to implement database synchronization in my administration panel. I will give it a try soon. https://github.com/IvanPrat/PHPDBSync

Comment: I don't think that syncing is a great idea, there may be parts of the dev database that are not ready to be moved to production, but this is your call.

Comment: Well, it depends on whether synchronizing is a good idea or not. I will sync when I am well aware that everything is ready to be synchronized.

Anyway, the PHPDBSync has got some problems, such as `Undefined variable: k_1 on line 371` and `Undefined variable: database on line 371`, so at least I tested the code from GitHub in my private production database (172.20.16.34) so I'm very happy I did. I'm going to look for another code in GibHub that is more developed than the code I found in GitHub.

Comment: I have decided to come up with a script that does a mysqldump with username and password already filled in, which pipes it to mysql with the same username and password filled in as well. I then name it dbsync.sh and then have the php's `shell_exec()` command inside the functions.php and then call the function from inside the controller class. I'm aware that shell_exec() and all the exec() line of functions is dangerous which is why I don't allow user input from the frontend. Copying all the structure and data is not everyone's idea, but I do have a use case for doing this, so it works.

Answer (score 0):

## Quick and Dirty Solution

What I have right now is to write a shell script that contains both the username and password for `mysqldump` and `mysql` commands.

### BASH Script

`/home/grayson/bin/sync-db.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Synchronizing data..."
mysqldump -u username -p'...' -h 172.20.16.32 graysonpeddie_blog | mysql -u username -p'...' -h 172.22.203.247 graysonpeddie_blog
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "OK"
fi
```

An else statement is not needed if there's an error message from either mysqldump or mysql.

### `DBSyncController` Controller Class

`/var/www/admin.graysonpeddie.com/controller/dbsynccontroller.php`

```
<?php

include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/includes/controller.inc";

class DBSyncController extends Controller
{
    public function httpget_index()
    {
        $this->View([]);
    }

    public function httpget_sync()
    {
        include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
            ."/includes/functions.inc";
        $this->View(["DBSync",dbsync_devprod()]);
    }
}
```

The `httpget_sync` method displays the results page.

### Function: Development to Production

```
<?php
function dbsync_devprod()
{
    return shell_exec('/home/grayson/bin/db-sync.sh');
}
```

Note that the `exec()` line of functions such as `shell_exec()` is a security risk, but because my administration panel resides in my home server and not in the Internet, the `shell_exec()` function is fine for me, for now.

## Long-Term Solution

I have made a BlogModel class so that it can connect to a local or remote database server. I have constructed a couple of sync state tables for MySQL. By "sync state," I meant something like this:

`/var/www/admin.graysonpeddie.com/model/blogmodel.php`

```
// Local database only
abstract class SyncState
{
    const CURRENT = 0; // No changes need to be made.
    const NEW     = 1; // A new blog article needs to be copied.
    const UPDATE  = 2; // Update the data in table in the remote database.
    const DELETE  = 3; // Delete the data from the table in remote database.
}
```

And I have a couple of sync state functions in my `BlogModel` class. All the administrative stored procedures look identical in the local and remote database except that the remote database does not contain tables and stored procedures for sync states.

```
    // Public functions for Sync states - local database only
    public function SetSyncState_BlogArticles($id,$syncstate)
    {
        $this->SetSyncState($id,$syncstate,"BlogArticles");
    }

    public function SetSyncState_BlogArticlesCategories($id,$syncstate)
    {
        $this->SetSyncState($id,$syncstate,"BlogArticlesCategories");
    }

    public function SetSyncState_BlogArticlesTags($id,$syncstate)
    {
        $this->SetSyncState($id,$syncstate,"BlogArticlesTags");
    }

    private function SetSyncState($id,$syncstate,$table)
    {
        if($this->local)
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("CALL SetSyncState_".$table."(?, ?)");
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(2, $syncstate, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
        } else die("Local database only. Can't set a sync state in the remote database.");
    }
```

I thought about creating two classes that extend the BlogModel class, but I want to keep it simplified.

### SQL

And a sample table containing all the states for each row.

#### Query

```
SELECT ba.BlogArticleID, ba.SyncState AS "BlogArticles",
       bac.SyncState AS "BlogArticlesCategories",
       bat.SyncState AS "BlogArticlesTags"
  FROM SyncState_BlogArticles ba
 INNER JOIN SyncState_BlogArticlesCategories bac ON ba.BlogArticleID = bac.BlogArticleID
 INNER JOIN SyncState_BlogArticlesTags bat ON ba.BlogArticleID = bat.BlogArticleID;
```

#### Result

```
+---------------+--------------+------------------------+------------------+
| BlogArticleID | BlogArticles | BlogArticlesCategories | BlogArticlesTags |
+---------------+--------------+------------------------+------------------+
|             1 |            0 |                      0 |                0 |
|             2 |            0 |                      0 |                0 |
|             5 |            0 |                      0 |                0 |
|             7 |            0 |                      0 |                0 |
|             8 |            0 |                      0 |                0 |
|             9 |            0 |                      0 |                0 |
|            10 |            0 |                      0 |                0 |
+---------------+--------------+------------------------+------------------+
```

`BlogArticleID` corresponds to my blog entires in my website (https://graysonpeddie.com). the three columns after that contain the state depending on whether a row needs to be added, updated, or deleted. If I were to set the state of BlogArticles to 1 for a BlogArticleID of 11, my administration panel will call a `$local->ShowBlogArticleByID(...)` to get the data from the local database and then copies the data to the remote database by calling `$remote->WriteBlogArticle(...)`. The $local and $remote variables are of `BlogModel` object.

So, in the table above, no changes will be made to the remote database.

### How Does That Work Once Completed?

Once I write a blog article, my admin panel will call `SetSyncState_BlogArticles()`, `SetSyncState_BlogArticlesCategories()`, and `SetSyncState_BlogArticlesTags()` to SyncState::NEW, which is 1.

After that, to synchronize my changes to the remote database, I simply go to "Synchronize Database" section of my administration panel and click in "Sync to Production Database." The WriteBlogArticle() gets called if the BlogArticles state is set to 1 and that state is "NEW."

What if I've deleted a blog article? Same thing but this time the article will be deleted and the row in the `graysonpeddie_blogadmin.SyncState_BlogArticles` table will be automatically deleted to maintain consistency with the `graysonpeddie_blog.BlogArticles` table.

And same for updating a data in the database.

However, I will be implementing a "dry run" to make sure I want to push changes before I do so in order to avoid mistakes in my production server. In that case, because I am still working in writing code for synchronizing from one local database to remote, I have another virtual machine setup as a playground. Perhaps a "staging" virtual machine to make sure everything is working before I push the changes to my production server.

## Summary

I elaborated a lot in my post about synchronizing from a local to a remote database server. Until I have fully implemented the code for synchronizing from local to remote database, I will still continue to use the crude solution of executing the shell script for now.

And yes, all this is a lot of work, but I have already challenged msyelf when I created my own blog engine from scratch! So what I did for my website (https://graysonpeddie.com) is considered a big project. That's why I don't use WordPress, Drupal, or any other turnkey CMS solutions out there! All I want is something very lightweight, is only targeted for a single author such as myself, is very secure from the ground up, and makes full use of MVC (Model-View-Controller) paradigm. And you know what? It worked! And all I need to do now is to write synchronization code and that's it!

I'm hoping my answer can be of help for those who need advice about how to setup manual synchronization for the remote database.